# Objective-C EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when using flexible length arrays

Tags: objective-c, struct, nsarray, flexible-array-member, exc-bad-access

I have done some testing on some behavior I have found, and I was wondering if someone can help me understand what is going on.

I have a struct, called `myStruct`, that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    float floats[];
} myStruct;
```

And I run this code on it:

```
int main () {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.2", @"0.5", @"0.5", nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", a);

    myStruct my;
    my.size = a.count;

    my.floats[0] = [[a objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    my.floats[1] = [[a objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    my.floats[2] = [[a objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];

    NSLog(@"{ %lf, %lf, %lf }", my.floats[0], my.floats[1], my.floats[2]);

    [a release];    
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine. However, when I change the struct declaration to this:

```
typedef struct {
    float myVar;
    int size;
    float floats[];
} myStruct;
```

I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when I call the line `[a release]`.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to actually allocate space for your flexible array member!  This line:

```
myStruct my;
```

Only makes enough stack space for `size` (or `myVar` and `size` from your second example).  It appears that in your failing case you're overwriting `a` on the stack, but really both cases are wrong.  To fix your problem, you need to allocate space for the `floats[]` member of the structure:

```
myStruct *my = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) + a.count * sizeof(float));
```

Don't forget to `free()` it when you're done!

A quick example - this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float myVar;
    int size;
    float floats[];
} myStruct;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(myStruct));
  return 0;
}
```

and its output:

```
$ make testapp
cc     testapp.c   -o testapp
$ ./testapp 
8
```

Comment: But then it's not on the stack ;) Don't forget to free it when you're done!

Comment: @deanWombourne - yes.  If the OP really needs a stack allocation for some reason, `alloca()` is there to help him out.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something simple :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not allocating any memory for your floats - I'm surprised it's not crashing sooner!

Do you need to malloc some memory for the floats[] pointer?

---

After a quick test I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS for both definitions of myStruct :)

Comment: `floats[]` isn't a pointer - it's a flexible array member.  You're right that the OP needs to allocate some space for that array, though!

Comment: oops, typing too fast. I actually have no idea how to allocate a flexible array on the stack in a nice way.

Comment: Ah, just seen your comment on your answer - I've never used `alloca()` before but it's handy to know about. Every day is a school day :)